# Edit a button more than once on a Discord bot using Nextcord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

So, I'm using Nextcord to make a Discord bot. I have some buttons that I would like to edit the style more than once.
At first, I tried with interaction.response.edit_message(), which works great once but the second time, it gives me this error:

nextcord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before

I learned that I can't use interaction.response more than once, so I knew I had to get creative here. I got suggested to use the interaction.edit() or interaction.message.edit().
interaction.message.edit() gives me that error even if I do it only once:

```
Ignoring exception in view <ChoicesView timeout=180.0 children=9> for item <ChoicesBtn style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Party' emoji=None row=0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/ui/view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 45, in callback
    await interaction.message.edit(view=self.view)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/message.py", line 1367, in edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_message(self.channel.id, self.id, **payload)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/http.py", line 333, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
nextcord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

If I use interaction.edit(), it works once but I get a very similar error if I do it twice.

```
Ignoring exception in view <ChoicesView timeout=180.0 children=9> for item <ChoicesBtn style=<ButtonStyle.secondary: 2> url=None disabled=False label='Birth' emoji=None row=2>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/ui/view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 46, in callback
    await interaction.edit(view=self.view)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/interactions.py", line 551, in edit
    return await self.message.edit(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/message.py", line 1367, in edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_message(self.channel.id, self.id, **payload)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/http.py", line 333, in request
    raise NotFound(response, data)
nextcord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10008): Unknown Message
```

I tried to manually change the state of interaction.response._responded attribute to False but then I got this error

```
Ignoring exception in view <ChoicesView timeout=180.0 children=9> for item <ChoicesBtn style=<ButtonStyle.success: 3> url=None disabled=False label='Party' emoji=None row=0>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/ui/view.py", line 371, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 47, in callback
    await interaction.edit(view=self.view)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/interactions.py", line 549, in edit
    return await self.response.edit_message(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/interactions.py", line 959, in edit_message
    await adapter.create_interaction_response(
  File "/home/runner/Raids-Master-buttons-labels/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/webhook/async_.py", line 191, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
nextcord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40060): Interaction has already been acknowledged.
```

I don't know what to try after that, I tried to read the interaction definition on GitHub but I admit that it's too much for me... I didn't share the code but all I'm doing is redefining the callback method on a custom class based on nextcord.ui.Button

I know it's a lot but I tried to give you as much information as possible. Thanks for taking the time and let me know if I wasn't clear enough on some things !!

Comment: Maybe create new `Button`s and add them to the message?

Comment: I would still have to edit the message to add the new view. It simply moves the problem but the issue remains:
I can't edit the message twice for some reason (or not easily anyway)

Comment: Did you try editing the *message* to include *new* buttons? I don't know the NextCord framework, but as you can (not sure) edit a normal (not the interaction) message how many ever times you want, I think you can try editing the message to replace the buttons with new ones.

Comment: Is the message ephemeral by any chance?

Comment: If the message was created by an interaction response, you can pass that interaction into the View constructor to access in the button callback and use edit_original_message on that other interaction object. If the message is ephemeral, this is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the button argument into the code you can use the button.style attribute to change the button style. You can also use button.label to change what the text is on the label.

Example which turns green and says Hi! when you click it:

```py
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands


# Define a simple View that gives us a counter button
class HelloButtons(nextcord.ui.View):

    
    @nextcord.ui.button(label="Press me!", style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def sayhi(self, button: nextcord.ui.Button, interaction: nextcord.Interaction):
        button.style = nextcord.ButtonStyle.green
        button.label="Thanks for pressing me!"
       
        await interaction.response.edit_message(view=self)


bot = commands.Bot()


@bot.slash_command()
async def counter(interaction):
    await interaction.send("Press the button!", view=HelloButtons())


bot.run("token")
```